# org-fill-paragraph doesn't comply with org-list-allow-alphabetical

Tags: org-mode, fill-paragraph, overlays, read-only-mode

Given that `(setq org-list-allow-alphabetical t)`.

Consider the following example, where `|` stands for the point:

```
1. |Lorem Ipsum
   1. Lorem Ipsum
```

```
1. |Lorem Ipsum
   a. Lorem Ipsum
```

While `org-fill-paragraph` does nothing in the first Org snippet, it collapses the two lines in the second:

```
1. Lorem Ipsum a. Lorem Ipsum
```

I'm working on a specific case where `read-only-mode` is in use and don't need to export the Org buffer to pdf or other file types. However, I have to keep the alphabetical numbering at least visually as the content refer to them as such. Hence, I'm currently considering a workaround which consists of

1. replacing alphabetical bullets by numeral ones ;
2. then using overlays with the `'display` property to display them as they were alphabetical bullets.

As the underlying bullets are numeral, `org-fill-paragraph` would work as expected.

Are there better solutions for this issue ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Org mode version 9.4.6 (release_9.4.6-553-g9aa304). Neither of the lists gets reformatted.

Comment: Did you run `(org-element-update-syntax)` or restart emacs after updating `org-list-allow-alphabetical`?

Comment: @NickD Ah, my bad. Looks like I didn't read the documentation thoroughly... Do you perhaps know why `org-list-allow-alphabetical` is not set to `t` by default ?

Comment: I don't know - the manual may point to a rationale:  confusion with normal text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NickD pointed out and per the documentation:

```
This variable needs to be set before org.el is loaded.  If you
need to make a change while Emacs is running, use the customize
interface or run the following code after updating it:

  ‘M-x org-element-update-syntax’
```

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @NickD Yeah, thanks. I was waiting the 48 hours.

Comment: I always forget about the 48 hours...